# Old 301 Redirect Showing in Search Results Despite Its Removal

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, 301-redirect, googlebot

One our upcoming eCommerce site was put on a 301 redirect few months back, while the background work was being done.

Now the website development has started and the 301 has been removed. We have submitted the website to Google through webmaster tools few days back and even used the "fetch" functionality.

Unfortunately, the crawler does not seem to be updating the listing for the website. It is still showing a redirected version.

Does google take more time to update (been several days now), or is this some stuck google cache or a bug?

Comment: It takes a few days even with Fetch as Google assuming that you then Submit to Index. Be patient. Search engines are not real-time or even close to real-time. The Internet is just so HUGE that it is impossible. It will work out.

Comment: @HappyBrain The correct domain does appear in the SERPs, not the previously redirected-to domain - so it does appear to have been updated? But... you have nothing on your site yet, so I'm not sure what you are expecting??

Comment: The original issue was, you should have used a 302 redirect since it was temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Submit a sitemap then fetch as Google and render > Submit to index.

Should be good to go within hours to 1 day.

Comment: @HappyBrain Because of abuse, Google does not actually update the index using the Fetch as Google and Submit to Index feature. Instead, the regular googlebot will visit 1-2 days later and update the index. It may be that this is taking longer these days. I have not used the feature in more than a year now. Cheers!!

Comment: @w3dk We have tons of content ready to be uploaded which will be done in the upcoming days and weeks. Since this little weird thing, I kept it on hold to see what was going on. If it just the internal links and content, then not really a problem since it would be populated in due course.

Comment: @HappyBrain Sorry, I moved my comment above as it didn't seem to be appropriate here (you replied quickly :) - But what you are seeing in the SERPs looks reasonably "normal". The correct domain is appearing the SERP (not the redirected-to domain - so _something_ has updated), but you need to add content to your site. Google isn't going to index your site if there is "nothing" to index.

Comment: @w3dk Duly noted. We will just start populating the site with product listings then. Thank you.